# Mail Merge Email Macro

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I am trying to create a macro to send a word document to 4 emails per document, each coming in from it's own field

e.g. supplier1mail, supplier2mail, etc. and is usually going to be sent in about 10 docs per batch, data is being pulled in from an access database and email is being sent through outlook.

Subject line will always be the same and no body text is needed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the first time I've really looked at 
VBA.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more extensive details and if you have some code too. It's a site to help you progress, so we need to see that you tried before coming here to ask.
Take a look : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not going to lie, prior to getting the below comment I hadn't tried anything with regards to VBA as I had no idea where to start with it.

Comment: No problem, I just happend to have a good start for what you are looking for so I gave it to you. When you start and don't know where to go, just type in google something like : [Application][Language][Issue]; so here you go : https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=word%20vba%20merge

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started, this how I did mine (before, set up your Mailing in Word) :

```
Sub MergeToEmail()
Dim DisPTxT As String

    Dim bDone As Boolean
    bDone = False

    Do While bDone = False

        ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

        With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
            .MailAddressFieldName = "Mail"
            .Destination = wdSendToEmail
            .SuppressBlankLines = True
            ' You can modify the text "Enter Your Subject Here" or
            ' remove the following line if you do not want a subject
            .MailSubject = "Samedi 26 Avril 2014"
            With .DataSource
                .FirstRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
                .LastRecord = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord
            End With
            .Execute Pause:=False
        End With

        If ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = _
            ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount Then
            bDone = True
        End If
        ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, getting some movement with it now, just a quick question, what does the DisPTxT As String variable apply to?  As it doesn't seem to do anything and is only referenced at initialization.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to get rid of it. I used it because I had some trouble with the text displayed in my hyperlinks with the merge (I was changing the link on every mail)

Comment: Ah no problem, thanks again for your help, have it running now for one email, so I'm thinking if I put the 4 email fields in an array and loop through that should cover the lot for me?

Comment: I have never done a Mail Merge with Access so I'm not sure, but I think that you need to check in Word more that a modification in code. For mine, I used an Excel and the header containing mails was `Mail` (ergo `.MailAddressFieldName = "Mail"`) so check if it is the same for you.